# Conceptual Difficulty c++ Deck of Cards

Tags: c++, oop

I know there are a ton of questions about this timeless implementation, but as a new OOP programmer i'm struggling to grasp the necessary concepts to make any ground.

Am I building an actual randomized deck in an array that would act as a playing card deck for any card game?  Or am I "replicating" a random playing card deck by creating 4 suits and then the 13 different faces?  I've seen multiple implementations and I don't quite understand what they're getting at.  The `int deck[];` is where I was planning to store the cards.  Would I populate that deck array when an instance of the deck of cards class was created?

My main merely has the print function called (that I have not written yet)

```
//Texas holdem build
//Will attempt using Classes and inheritance
//Full build for up to 6 players

#include <iostream>
#include "deckOfCards.h"

int main()
{

    DeckOfCards deck;

    deck.printDeck();

    return(0);
}
```

Header

```
* deckOfCards.h
 *
 *  Created on: Jun 28, 2016
 *      Author: TAmend
 */

#ifndef DECKOFCARDS_H_
#define DECKOFCARDS_H_

class DeckOfCards
{

    public:
        DeckOfCards();
        void printDeck() const;
        void shuffle();

    private:
        int currentCard;
        int deck[];

};

#endif /* DECKOFCARDS_H_ */
```

Comment: For the sake of learning and speaking as OOP designs. A `Deck of Cards` would be a container of `52 objects` and not just `int`s. So, another small struct/class would represent a `card`. What does that card(class) have? It has a suit (1 out of the 4), a value(1/13) and a face (1/13). Then in your `Deck of cards` class, there would be a function that will populate 52 objects of that small class(card) into its own private member container, making sure no duplicates within the cards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, having a `Card` `class` or `struct` and a `DeckOfCards` class that acts as a specialized container is the right way to go (as was mentioned in [@Thomas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38128123/1413395)):

```
struct Card
{
  enum Suit_Type {
      Diamonds,
      Hearts,
      Spades,
      Clubs,
  } suit;
  enum Value_Type {
      Two = 2, // <<<<<<<<< Note starts at 2
      Three ,
      // Four, Five, Six, aso. ...
      Ten ,
      Jack ,
      Queen ,
      King ,
      Ace , // <<<<<<<<< Note has the highest value here
  } value;
  void printCard();
};
```

---

```
 void Card::printCard() {
      switch(suit) {
      case Hearts:
          std::cout << "♥";
          break;
      case Diamonds:
          std::cout << "♦";
          break;
      case Clubs:
          std::cout << "♣";
          break;
      case Spades:
          std::cout << "♠";
          break;
      }
      if(value < Jack) {
         std::cout << (int)value;
      }
      else {
          switch(value) {
          case Jack:
              std::cout << 'J';
              break;
          case Queen:
              std::cout << 'Q';
              break;
          case King:
              std::cout << 'K';
              break;
          case Ace:
              std::cout << 'A';
              break;
          }
      }
  }
```

---

As also was mentioned, there should be some comparison operators implemented on `Card`, to make implementation of the gameplay easier:

```
  bool operator<(const Card& lhs, const Card& rhs) {
       return (lhs.suite < rhs.suite) &&
              (lhs.value < rhs.value);
  }

  bool operator>(const Card& lhs, const Card& rhs) {
       return (lhs.suite > rhs.suite) &&
              (lhs.value > rhs.value);
  }
```

Note that the implementation of an equality test doesn't make much sense from a semantical view, unless you want to play with multiple `DeckOfCards` at the same time.

How `Cards` should behave in a particular game, might be completely delegated to a [Strategy Pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy/cpp/1) class.

---

A `DeckOfCards` can be initialized from an appropriate initializer list:

```
class DeckOfCards {
     DeckOfCards() : cards_({
         { Diamonds, Two } ,
         // ...
         { Diamonds, Ace } ,
         { Hearts, Two } ,
         // ...
         { Hearts, Ace } ,
         { Spades, Two } ,
         // ...
```

```
         { Spades, Ace } , // !!! Extremely important !!!
```

```
         { Clubs, Two } ,
         // ...
         { Clubs, Ace } ,
     }) {}

     void printDeck();
     void shuffle();

private:
     std::array<Card,52> cards_;
};
```

---

The other functions can be implemented easy as that then:

```
void DeckOfCards::printDeck() {
    bool first = true;
    for(auto card : cards_) {
         if(!first) {
             std::cout << ", ";
         }
         card.printCard();
         first = false;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void DeckOfCards::shuffle() {
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 g(rd());

    std::shuffle(cards_.begin(), cards_.end(), g);
};
```

---

I'm not a 100% sure what you want to achieve with the `currentCard` member in `DeckOfCards`, but I'd suppose you wan't that being the offset to the next `Card` to hand out from a `DeckOfCards`, so you can simply use it as an index for the `cards_` array, to hand out a reference to the underlying `Card` instance, and increment it afterwards:

```
 const Card& getNextCard(bool& cardsAvailable) {
      cardsAvailable = true;
      if(currentCard < 52) {
          return cards_[currentCard++];
      }
      // Reset the deck
      cardsAvailable = false;
      currentCard = 0;
      shuffle();
 }
```

---

<sub>Go find the easter egg</sub>

Comment: I've never heard clubs called "cross". Also, the value of an ace is dependent on the game. In some games, all face cards have the same value.

Comment: @RobK THX for the insight, I'm not a native speaker and got that from a translation site. Well, of course the ordering of values depends on the actual game played, but most card games use this ordering (small correction in the suites).

Comment: In most places you use `Deck` but the class is defined as `DeckOfCards`. I'm guessing it's just a copy/paste mistake.

Comment: @JamesAdkison Yes, I was missing to change `Deck` to `DeckOfCards` from my original answer. Hope I caught all ocurrences now.

Comment: I am pretty sure it is not easter yet but +1

Answer (score 1):

I have answered these before, so I will do so again.

IMHO, there are two objects:  a *container* of cards and a card.  Don't mix them.

Let us start with a card.  A card has a suit and a value:

```
struct Card
{
  Suit_Type suit;
  Value_Type value;
};
```

The container can be anything, such as `std::vector`, `std::list`, or my favorite `std::deque`. ;-)

```
typedef std::vector<Card> Deck_Of_Cards;
```

You could make your own container, but for most assignments using cards, there is no need.  Prefer an existing container data structure.

As far as the types inside the `Card` struct, a matter of preference.  You can use enum, string or whatever for the `Suit_Type`.  Similarly with the `Value_Type`.

To make the Cards more usable, you should implement the following methods in the `Card` struct:

1. Constructors, assignment operators, destructors.
2. Equality and ordering operators (e.g. ==, and <)
3. Stream insertion and extraction (e.g. >> and <<)

Also look at the function `std::random_shuffle`.

Comment: _"I have answered these before, so I will do so again."_ Isn't this a dupe then?

Comment: I haven't given a complete answer before, just suggestions. :-)

Comment: Well, you may try to give a complete answer now then (BTW, since the number of cards in a _deck_ is usually fixed, I'd rather recommend `std::array<>` as the internal container type).

Comment: `std::random_shuffle` is deprecated. Just use `std::shuffle`.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ for a deck of just 52 elements that never grows/shrinks I'd say it doesn't actually matter - performance wise.

Comment: One can use `std::vector` and `reserve` 52 slots.  The `std::vector` works on older versions of C++ as well. :-)

Comment: @ThomasMatthews _"Constructors, assignment operators, destructors."_ Compiler generated default functions would just suffice here.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, just to make it super clear, your deck class is going to act as a 'container' class. This means it will hold a bunch of cards of type card; not int.

In the end, the array you use to to store your cards will look something like 
Card deck[]; instead of int deck[]; This will allow you to add any properties you like to each individual card.

You can randomize each property of the Card class at construction or just before and pass the random values in.

For the sake of helping you understand:

```
class Card
{
public:
    Card(int value): value(value) {}
    int Getvalue(){ return value; }
private:
    int value;
};



class DeckOfCards
{

public:
 //   DeckOfCards();
 //   void printDeck() const;
  //  void shuffle();
    void createDeck()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < deck_size; i++)    //Implementation of createDeck
            deck[i] = new Card(rand()%10-1);//whatever val you want to generate
    }

private:
 //   int currentCard;
  //  Card deck[];

};
```

In this way you can grab the cards whenever you want, and add whatever properties you want e.g. suit.

NOTE: a vector would be preferable to a primitive array but don't just drop the DeckOfCards class because if you do then where do you store your shuffledeck function or your printdeck function? etc... Instead simply replace the member array with a vector.

Comment: _"a vector would be preferable ..."_ In fact a `std::array<Card,52>` would be the correct internal standard container type. No need for dynamic memory allocation in this case.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Agree 100%

Comment: It wasn't made clear what type of card game/deck it's supposed to be which is why I omitted the suit property. Also, yes a normal array, allocating it's members from the stack would be fine but what if you want to remove an element, again it's not made clear what type of game/deck it is.                                                                                     You could use a standard array, it's all down to how you want to manage removal of each card from the array(if at all).

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you want to achieve with your deck of cards, how you want to use it. In some instances, a simple `int[]` will be entirely sufficient for your needs. In others, you will need the full card and deck classes, and other helper classes. The card and deck implementations given in other answers are (unwittingly?) specialized for certain card games, and totally unusable for others. Don't ask what you can have, ask yourself what you need. [Do the simplest thing that could possibly work.](https://www.google.com/search?q=Do+the+simplest+thing+that+could+possibly+work&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

(And really this question is too broad/opinion based and might be more at home on programmers.stackexchange.com)